# Requirement already satisfied- pymysql in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.8.0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip, virtualenv

I implemented the python flask application, created the vitual environment and activated it. When I try to install pymysql to it, Following messages is shown on the terminal.

```
Requirement already satisfied: pymysql in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.8.0)
```

But when I try to run it. It gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pymysql
ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

Comment: Ensure you are running the program from same environment. Check using `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same Python3 to execute your app.py file.

to make yourself sure that you're using the same version of python i recommend you to to proceed as follow :

```
$ python --version  
  python X.X

$ pythonX.X -m pip install pymsql

$ python app.py
```